# Initialize an object with override

Tags: c#

Is it possible to initialize an object with some equivalent to override in place of the new operator?

Say I have some object, and I want to cast it to some derived type. 
Lets call them objBase and objDerived.

So suppose this objDerived type has a method which uses new modifier on an objBase method but I want to use the new method with my cast objBase object.
Is there some way of saying something equivalent to:

```
objBase myObjB = new objBase();
myObjB = *override* objDervied();
```

Maybe it makes no sense to want to do this or there's some terribly simple alternative I'm missing? I'm pretty sure some contrived example could show some time when it could be useful though...
I don't actually need to do this but I was just wondering about it the last few days since I learned about the new modifier keyword in methods.

Comment: While you can assign a *new* instance of `objDerived` to an `objBase` (reference) variable, you can't change the type of an *existing* `objBase` so that this very object becomes a `objDerived`.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to reconstruct `myObjB` as `objDerived` while retaining its current state? Not that I know of. If there is some obscure feature that does this, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Are you just experimenting with the `new` keyword or are you actually trying to solve a problem? because I'm getting curious to what you are trying to achieve :). Funny question though! +1 :)

Comment: Yeah that was my guess Andre but I figured I'd never know unless I ask. I think Reed Copseys answer below gives a good solution the problem though. @bas Just learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to override, in this case.  You can always assign a derived object reference to a base class variable directly:

```
objBase myObjB = new objDerived();
```

Note that it's also not good practice to create an instance, then reassign immediately:

```
// Don't instantiate an object in the first line here, 
// since you're going to assign it in the next line
objBase myObjB;  //= new objBase();
myObjB = new objDervied();
```

As for:

> So suppose this objDerived type has a method which uses new modifier on an objBase method but I want to use the new method with my cast objBase object.

You can only call the `new` method which hides the base class method by assigning or casting back to the derived class:

```
objBase myObjB = new objDerived();
((objDerived)myObjB).Method(); // Will call objDerived.Method
```

This will fail at runtime if `myObjB` does not actually reference an `objDerived` instance.

The other option here would be to use `dynamic`.  Using `dynamic` for your variable will cause dynamic dispatching to occur, which will make the variable effectively behave as if it's always the "most derived" type, and call your new method. This is actually useful in that you can effectively do [multiple dispatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) in C#, even though it's normally statically typed.  Here is a complete working sample:

```
void Main()
{
    Base b = new Derived();  
    dynamic d = b;
    Console.WriteLine(d.Output());//This prints "Derived"
}

public class Base {
public string Output() {
        return "Base";
}
}

public class Derived:  Base {
    public new string Output() {
        return "Derived";
}
}
```

Comment: @Redd - why not initialize? Even ReSharper initialization with declaration.

Comment: @AppDeveloper I said don't initialize *if you're going to reassign* immediately.  In that specific case, you're running the construction code + using the memory for the object, then just throwing it away.

Comment: I had actually written a few lines more to elaborate the question and pass the objBase to the objDerived's constructor but decided it was overkill, then forgot to remove the initial initialization. As for the casting to call the method, that's exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
objBase myObjB = new objDervied();
```

Comment: that's not the same. A function that has been made in objDerived with new modifier will not be hit if I call it from myObjB in this case.

Comment: this will not work with *new* modifier on member of the Derived class.

Answer (score 1):

No way!

You can't override a member during run-time.

This would be more a feature for a dynamic language rather than a statically-typed and compiled language like C#. For example, you would do this in JavaScript as you can reuse identifiers on run-time:

```
var someJsObject = { myMethod: function() { } };
someJsObject.myMethod = function() { alert("hey, I did it!"); };
```

By the way, I don't find this a good practice because one thing is having a dynamic language (*duck typing*) and other is "hey, I'm a duck, I used to say *quack quack* but now I'm a barking duck!". It's sad.

### Update

*Well...* In fact you could do something like this using C# and an `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.MyMethod = new Func<bool>(() => true);

dynamic expando2 = new ExpandoObject();
expando.MyMethod = new Func<string>(() => "What? I've changed!");

expando.MyMethod = expando2.MyMethod;
            
// This will set "What? I've changed!"
string result = expando.MyMethod();
```

But it's still a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

> So suppose this objDerived type has a method which uses new modifier
>   on an objBase method but I want to use the new method with my cast
>   objBase object

What you're asking for is something like this I presume:

```
public class Base {
   public string Write() {
        return "Base";
   }
}

public class Derived:  Base {

    public new string Write() { //HIDES BASE CLASS METHOD
        return "Derived";
   }
}


void Main()
{
    Base b = new Derived();  
    b.Write();//THIS WILL RETURN "BASE"

    Derived d = new Derived();  
    d.Write();//THIS WILL RETURN "DERIVED"
}
```

You **can not** do that, as `new` on the member of the derived class overrides *only* concrete object *type*.

To work in a way you want it do, so working only with base type, you need use basic OOP concept, like `inheritance` and `virtual/absrtact` methods.